# How to put white spaces in JLaTeXMath

Tags: spacing

We are using JLatexMath library in java project to export some expression into JLatexMath.
Code:

```
texCode="\\mathrm {let} {x}"
```

It shows `Letx`.
What I need is `Let x`, space between `Let` and `x`.
Does anybody knows how to put spaces between them.
Thanks forward.

Answer (score 2):

let *x* ....

is really a text sentence rather than math so would normally be marked up as

```
Let $x$ be ....
```

with just the math bits in math, but perhaps your library only makes math expressions so you could do

```
 $\mbox{Let } x ... $
```

with `\mbox` giving a nested text context in which a space produces a word space. Apparently the `$` are implicitly added by your API so you wouldn't need them.

Comment: By default JLaTeXmath is in math mode. So the previous solution is the a good one. You can also use \text{let $x$}. Regards, Calixte